# Programmatically spin up additional Jenkins nodes via ec2-plugin

Tags: jenkins

We use Jenkins with [ec2-plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ec2/) to dynamically spin up ec2 nodes when they're needed and dispose them off when they're not. In certain situation when we know and anticipate heavy use, we warm up additional nodes via the nodes management page by clicking on the "Provision Via ... " button.

How can this be achieved programmatically? Either as a scripted pipeline job (preferred) or a console script so warming up nodes is not a manual operation?

Comment: I'll juar refer you to my [SuperUser responses](https://superuser.com/q/1604808/497981). Check links; I have no direct experience w/ec2 to say yea or nay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
def cloud = jenkins.clouds.getByName(env.CLOUD_NAME)

def label = jenkins.getLabel(env.NODE_LABEL)
def template = cloud.getTemplate(label)

def provision = cloud.provision(template, numberNodes)
```