# What value needs to be passed to Jenkins.CloudList.getByName() when using EC2 plugin?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, groovy

I'm using the [Jenkins EC2 plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ec2/), and attempting to retrieve the configured cloud programatically in Groovy (to provision nodes automatically as per [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65150163/programmatically-spin-up-additional-jenkins-nodes-via-ec2-plugin)).

The name I have configured for this Cloud is 'bulk_runner' (at {jenkins_url}/configureClouds/), but when I pass this to the [getByName function](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/jenkins/model/Jenkins.CloudList.html#getByName(java.lang.String)) like so `Jenkins.getInstance().clouds.getByName('bulk_runner')` the value returned is `null`.

If I access the element via an index, like so `Jenkins.getInstance().clouds[0]`, the value of this (when printed) is *hudson.plugins.ec2.AmazonEC2Cloud@49edfdb1*, the result of `Jenkins.getInstance().clouds[0].getDisplayName()` is *bulk_runner* and the result of `Jenkins.getInstance().clouds[0].getDescriptor()` is *hudson.plugins.ec2.AmazonEC2Cloud$DescriptorImpl@1592de56*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: Try to add `ec2-` prefix to the name, in this case `ec2-bulk_runner`.

**Longer answer**: Looks like the `getDisplayName()` function returns the name from configuration but the `name` property returns a unique identifier for the cloud which is actually used by `clouds.getByName()` function [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/c98beece641f168fbb20595d0a5623c599fb1968/core/src/main/java/jenkins/model/Jenkins.java#L546).

You can ensure what is the `name` in your case by reading it manually first:

```
println Jenkins.get().clouds.collect { it.name }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. I also did a bit of a work-around, by iterating over the clouds and finding the one that matched:
```
    def Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
    
    jenkins.clouds.each { cloud ->
        if ((cloud as AmazonEC2Cloud).getCloudName() == 'bulk_runner') {
            println "got cloud: " + cloud
        }
    }
```